# Dynamically generate accompanying model in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.11

In my project i have many models in multiple apps, all of them inherit from one abstract model. I would like to create a model that would hold the changes to the history for every one of my models, so that every model would have its own history model. Each model would also have one-to-many relation to its history model. All history models would be the same, except for the foreign key to their respective model.

My problem is that I do not want to write all the history models manually. Instead i would like to have the history model created for every model automatically, so I don't have to write all that boilerplate code. Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

There is a widely-used django package that I believe solves this exact problem called [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) with a nice API. I recommend using it if it fits your needs rather than building a custom solution.

---

Object version control is usually better solved by serializing your objects and storing the serialization every time they are edited (e.g. in the json format).
You may also want to keep track of when objects are deleted.

This way, you only need to store a reference to the serialized object. Versions of all objects can live in the same database table and reference their "source" object using [Django's generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

Comment: django-reversion does not fit my needs unfortunately.
The changes will be stored as json, so the history model is not going to look anything like the base model, instead it would inherit from its own base model.
As for the generic fk, It would mean creating very big table (I have tens of models, few of which at the start will have 200k records, so at the start the history model would probably get over a million records)

Answer (score 0):

You can eventually create your classes dynamically with `type()`

There is many ways to do it, but you can do something as follows:

```
class SomeParentClass: pass

NewClass = type('NewClass', (SomeParentClass,), {'new_method': lambda self: 
'foo' } )

new_class_instance = NewClass()
print(new_class_instance.new_method())
```

So you can create models dynamically, with a different name, inherit from a different class, new methods...

You can then use `globals()[variable_name_to_store_class]` to assign newly created classes to a dynamic variable name.
Hope its relavant for your problem.

Comment: I was thinking of something like that, but the problem is I need to create an accompanying model for all models subclassing one abstract model. I'm trying to iterate over all models using apps.get_models(), but obviously that fails with AppRegistryNotReady exception. I don't know any other way to access all models sublcassing my abstract model, that would get them even before they are loaded.
I was thinking that maybe it could work similarly to how M2M field creates a through model dynamically, but I don't know how this is achieved.

Comment: Maybe you need to create the accompanying model when the children of your abstract model is created/instantiated. You could do the trick with `type()` in the `__init__()` of the children of your abstract class. In this fashion, you don't need to access the children, just override their code.

Comment: Well, I tried it but it didn't work, because `__init__` is executed on object initialization instead of loading of a model. However, i found out that django-simple-history does very similar thing to what i want to do, so I'm going to try to solve it like they do (by defining contribute_to_class method). If that fails i will probably try to overwrite the `__new__` method on my model meta class.